# JSFiddle CSS and Result text areas squeezed

Tags: macos, google-chrome, jsfiddle

I am using Chrome on OSX and have encountered an infuriating bug which makes JSFiddle unusable:

[image: My unusable JSFiddle]

As the screenshot shows the CSS and Result text areas are squeezed off the screen with no handle to pull them back. **How can I make them visible and usable?**

It hasn't always rendered like this, but I'm not sure what has caused it.

---

## What I've tried

- Disabling all chrome extensions
- Resizing the browser to a ridiculous width
- Clearing local, session and cookie storage for JSFiddle on Chrome
- Removing secondary screens
- Changing my screen resolution

None of which have changed anything.

---

## Update

The bug is not replicated when using safari.

Comment: this question should be may migrated to superuser